# Github Fatal erorr

Tags: python, github, file-upload

I am trying to push files to my repo on Github and I am getting this error:

Client_loop :send-disconnect: Connection reset by peer fatal: shal file '' write error: Broken pipe send-pack: unexpected disconnect whle reading sideband packet fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly (base)

[image]
I have looked all over for help with this but google and youtube haven't helped me solve this. I am currently using pandas and jupyter notebook for my python code.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the error persists, in case of a GitHub incident.

But check also if changing protocol helps:

```
git remove -v
```

If this starts with HTTPS, try and switch to SSH (after checking your [SSH keys work](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection))

But if protocol does not help, apply the tool [github/git-sizer](https://github.com/github/git-sizer) to check if you have an element which would be too big for the push to complete successfully.